# Creating columns for each category in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. I have a table with data for different companies.

For example :

```
Company type count
--------------------
St1    sync    20
St2    async   30
St3    async   40
St3    sync    100
St1    async   90
St2    sync    65
```

Here, I'd like to print a report with `sync` and `async` as separate columns.

```
Company  sync   async
----------------------
St1      20     90
St2      65     30
St3      100    40
```

I've tried different queries, but can't really get the logic to implement it.

```
SELECT Company, 
(CASE WHEN type='async' THEN count END) as async,
(CASE WHEN type='sync' THEN count END) as sync,
FROM table
GROUP BY Company;
```

Included a query I've tried above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    Company,
    MAX(count) FILTER (WHERE type = 'sync')  AS sync,
    MAX(count) FILTER (WHERE type = 'async') AS async
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Company
ORDER BY
    Company;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: J.A.R.V.I.S. is always standing by ready to help you `:-)`